# How to create a popup mask in an iOS app using Kony Visualizer software?

Tags: ios

I'm a complete beginner with Kony Visualizer, and I'd like to know how to create a popup mask in it. I'm hoping that the popup mask can cover both the status bar and the home indicator.
I've also attached a design draft for your reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prw6i.png)

Because I'm a novice and not very familiar with app development, I'm unable to create a popup. I'm hoping someone can provide guidance and clarify whether a popup mask can cover the area including the status bar and home indicator. Could you please assist?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.